# Github Pages Build of Jekyll site is missing pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to use Github pages with Jekyll. Most of my pages are displayed as expected, but others (that I can see in the local build) do not show on the Github pages build.

The pages that do work are in the _pages folder with their permalinks set in the front matter. Like this

```
---
type: page
permalink: /about/
layout: default
---
```

The pages that don't work are in a folder _projects with similar, but slightly different front matters

```
---
permalink: /projects/foo
layout: post
---
```

When I try to access foo.com/projects/foo/ it gives me error 404, but foo.com/about/ works as expected. There are no front matter defaults, so what you see is what is there.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution in the similar questions as I was writing this, but couldn't with a google search.

Github Pages didn't like having the permalinks for _projects in the format `/projects/foo/`, but `/projects/foo.html` works like a charm.